# Alternatives to Firefox 3.5/POW to use SSJS?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, webserver

I have to install FFX 3.5 on my 11.04 machine. It's needed because I'm helping a friend of mine in a project involving Server-Side Javascript, and he is using POW webserver, actually avaliable for Linux only as a Firefox AddOn. (I know it's a dumb thing)
The addon is compatible only with FFX 3.5 and older, but I cant' find any official package of Firefox 3.5 for linux. 
So the questions are two:

1. Where can i find a package of Firefox 3.5 for linux? [SOLVED]
2. **Is there any alternative SSJS webserver out there? IT's main use will be displaying ssjs files in the browser (possibly on-the-fly, that means I have not to create a webserver in SSJS, like in the case of nodejs)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Firefox 3.5.19, as well as older versions of 3.5 from Mozilla's ftp framework. The timing is not the best right now, as the framework seems to be heavily overloaded, probably due to Firefox 5 release. The connection timed out many times for me, before being able to reach the files to verify their existence, but you might have better luck or might have to wait. Anyway, here it is:

ftp://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/3.5.19/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-3.5.19.tar.bz2

Once downloaded, extract it, and you'll get a folder called 'firefox' with precompiled binaries (meaning there is no need to install). You can run it from that folder with './firefox -P 3.5' where 3.5 is the name of the new profile. You can also move the folder somewhere convenient to you and create a launcher.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If nobody answers the other question I think this will be the marked answer :)